# ImageResizer url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, imageresizer

I'm looking for the best practice for my situation. I want to have different folders for different image size or preset:

```
/productimages/small/product1.jpg
/productimages/small/product2.jpg
/productimages/large/product1.jpg
/productimages/large/product2.jpg
```

or

```
/productimages/product1.jpg/small
/productimages/product2.jpg/small
/productimages/product1.jpg/large
/productimages/product2.jpg/large
```

Which Url format should I use? Should I use multiple VirtualFolder plugins with different virtual paths that point to the same physical path and use the Rewrite function?  Is there a better way to do this?

```
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/productimages/small", physicalPath="D:\images" />
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/productimages/large", physicalPath="D:\images" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using URL Rewriting - any kind works. VirtualFolder isn't contributing here - the rewriting will do everything you need.